# Need help finding a formula for question that was solved by trial and error

Tags: geometry, area

The following question can be worked out by trial and error, but is there a formula that can be used?

L shaped room has perimeter of 48m and area of 80m2. What is the length of each wall?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, unless you know more specifics about that L shape.

Comment: There seems to be 4 variables but only 2 relations, do you have any restrictions on the sizes of the sides?

Comment: No restriction on the size of sides, probably just whole numbers. It was a question in a maths test. I got a answer by trial and error, but wondering if there was a faster or 'proper' way to get a answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perimeter of L-shaped room is the same as bounding rectangle, and area of L-shaped room is area of bounding rectangle minus area of dropped rectangle. Let size of bounding rectangle (meter related units) is $a\times b$ and size of dropped rectangle is $c\times d$, then $$a+b=24,ab-cd=80,a>c>0,b>d>0$$

Without loss of generality we can suppose $a\geq b$. Excluding $b$ gives

$$a\geq 12,a(24-a)-cd=80,0<c<a, 0<d<24-a$$

$$cd=-a^2+24a-80=-(a-4)(a-20)>0 \Rightarrow a < 20$$

To find all positive integer solutions one can overlook all possible $a$ and check for $b,c,d$:

$$\begin{aligned} & a=12, b=24-a=12, cd=ab-80=64, c=8,d=8\\
& a=13, b=11, cd=63, c=9,d=7 {\rm\ or\ } c=7,d=9\\
& a=14, b=10, cd=60, c=12, d=5 {\rm\ or\ } c=10, d=6\\
& a=15, b=9, cd=55, c=11, d=5\\
& a=16, b=8, cd=48, c=12,d=4 {\rm\ or\ }c=8,d=6\\
& a=17, b=7, cd=39, c=13,d=3\\
& a=18, b=6, cd=28, c=14,d=2{\rm\ or\ }c=7,d=4\\
& a=19, b=5, cd=15, c=15,d=1{\rm\ or\ }c=5,d=3\end{aligned}$$

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for that